# Set the product name based on price, if price is zero or -1 or null ignore those products

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

Hi here i have whole bunch of products with different json objects. I have to get the product name based on the price. If price is not zero or not null get that product.

Comment: what you posted is not a valid json. Would you mind posting the valid json?

Comment: @Rao posted the valid one.

Comment: Prathyusha, what is the product name expected for the price 124.99?

Comment: @Rao "Yealink W56P with Power Supply Purchase" in the products Object. The first name in the json.

Comment: That was question because, the value you mentioned at many times in the json. Can you just refer which one in the hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry for confusion!.The first name in the hierarchy " "id": "2c92c0f85aff3453015b113678592b23",
    "sku": "SKU-00000218",
    "name": "Yealink W56P with Power Supply Purchase",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140131/discussion-between-prathyusha-and-rao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script:

Below script will traverse thru the json and extracts the product name where there is price and also put the data into a map called `productPriceMap` which can be used later.

```
def productPriceMap = [:]
def jsonParsed = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
jsonParsed.products.collect{ product ->
    product.productRatePlans.collect { ratePlan ->
       ratePlan.productRatePlanCharges.collect { charge ->
           charge.productRatePlanChargeTiers.collect{ tier ->
                if (tier.price) {
                   log.info "${tier.price} - ${product.name}"
                   productPriceMap[product.name] = tier.price
                }
           }
       }
    }
}
log.info "Product and price map\n$productPriceMap"
```

[image]

You can quickly try this online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5097242826375168)</kbd>

I am sure this can be shortened / more groovified. But this is what I could get it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is filtering a certain list. So it gives you some result, but has to be stored somewhere to use it further.

Like this

```
def toList(priceNullCheck){
    def filteredList = [priceNullCheck].flatten().findAll { it != null}
    log.info filteredList
}
```

Else you can return `[priceNullCheck].flatten().findAll { it != null}` directly

UPDATED

```
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult

def groovyUtils  = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def response = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("TestRequest#Response")

def collectResult = []

use (groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory) {
for( node in response.getDomNodes("//*:products//*:e")) {
    def eachNodeAsXml = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(nodeToString(node))
    String priceTagValue = eachNodeAsXml.getNodeValue("//*:price")
     float price = priceTagValue?Float.parseFloat(priceTagValue):0
     if(price>0)
        collectResult.add(eachNodeAsXml.getNodeValue("/*:name"))
    }
}

println collectResult

def nodeToString(def node)
{
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: But i am not getting what i am expecting, first getting all the price values in a string and then converting it to list. Then i have to check for price not equals to zero, or less than 0 and null.then have to set the product name.

Comment: Oh! I thought you had problem with only that snippet :D. Anyhow, try with the code posted.